# Angular 9 - Backend with Firebase and Cloud Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

For the front end (Angular) have a server and the back end is in Firebase i am using Cloud Firestore.

I tried database realtime, and everything ok, but I want to try Cloud Firestore and its collections.

The problem is the following:

This is the component:

```
 items: Array<any>;

  constructor(private aboutUsService: AboutUsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    this.aboutUsService.getContent()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.items = data;
      console.log('items: ',  this.items);
    }, // Bind to view
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

This is the service:

```
  getContent() {
    return this.db.collection('aboutus').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

At the moment I have a collection in Cloud Firestore:

[image: Cloud Firestore Collection]

Rules Cloud Firestore:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

The service responds and returns the following array with an element (this is the content of this.items):

```
[{…}]
0:
payload: {type: "added", doc: n, oldIndex: -1, newIndex: 0}
type: "added"
```

These are the headers in the Chrome network tab:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4200/aboutus
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:4200
```

But I am not able to find the data of the collection to display it in the front-end (variable this.items).

If I add elements to the collection "aboutus" in the response the array, it corresponds to the elements of the collection, but I don't get to visualize the data.

What could be the problem? Thank you

Comment: You should be using `AngularFirestoreCollection.valueChanges`, which returns an Observable of the value of the collection while `AngularFirestoreCollection.snapshotChanges` shows additional metadata on snapshots. For more info, consider viewing the documentation: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md

Comment: Ok, I have based on this example https://angular-templates.io/tutorials/about/angular-crud-with-firebase, I review it and comment, thanks

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly with "ValueChanges", I will study the documentation, thank you very much.

Comment: @Edric, since using AngularFirestoreCollection.valueChanges works perfectly as confirmed. Please post that info as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what I'd mentioned in my comment from over 2 weeks ago (on 15 May):

> You should be using `AngularFirestoreCollection.valueChanges`, which returns an `Observable` of the value of the collection while `AngularFirestoreCollection.snapshotChanges` shows additional metadata on snapshots. For more info, consider viewing the documentation: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md

As such, you should replace the `snapshotChanges` call with `valueChanges`:

```js
getContent() {
  return this.db.collection('aboutus').valueChanges();
}
```